# jquery remove/hide list option not containg string value from other list

Tags: jquery

I have a problem updating select options.

```
<select id="all">
    <option value="Volvo_A">Volvo_A</option>
    <option value="Volvo_B">Volvo_B</option>
    <option value="Volvo_C">Volvo_C</option>
    <option value="Saab_A">Saab_A</option>
    <option value="Saab_B">Saab_B</option>
    <option value="Saab_C">Saab_C</option>
    <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="Mercedes_A">Mercedes_A</option>
    <option value="Mercedes_B">Mercedes_B</option>
    <option value="Mercedes_C">Mercedes_C</option>
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="Audi_A">Audi_A</option>
    <option value="Audi_B">Audi_B</option>
    <option value="Audi_C">Audi_C</option>
</select>

<select id="type">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="Filter">Filter</button>
```

I want to update select list with id all based on value from select list with id type using Jquery. For example if volvo is selected from select with id type, then all option which do not contain volvo in select list with id all should be hidden temporarily.
How can I achieve this.

I tried the following code but did not work.

```
$( "#Filter" ).click(function( event ) {
  var filter = $("#type").val();
  $("#all > option[value != filter]").remove();
});
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Post your own attempt!

Comment: now I have added code that I tried but it did not work.

Comment: If you .remove() then they are gone.  If you want to be able to change type and filter again then you need to hide/disabled instead.  Also you are not matching exact values but substrings.

Comment: i dont need to match exact value in this case.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/H2eCw/

```
$( "#Filter" ).click(function( event ) {
  var filter = $("#type").val();
    console.log($("#all > option:not([value^=\"Volvo\"])"));
            console.log(filter);
    $("#all > option").show();
    $("#all > option:not([value^=\""+filter+"\"])").hide();
    $("#all").val($('#all>option:visible:first').val());
           //$("#all > option:not[value ^= "+filter+"]").remove();
});
```

Hide/Show instead of Remove..

Comment: hi i tried this, but it seems to be looking for exact match.
How can I change this [value^=\""+filter+"\"] so as to match substr.
eg. abc should match def_abc_xyf.
Thanks

Comment: @rkrara just change the `^=` to `*=` so it would be `$("#all > option:not([value*=\""+filter+"\"])").hide();`  thats like saying, value contains filter

Comment: Heres a chart I use alot when starting jquery.. https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/154_cheatsheet/jquery12_colorcharge.png

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Before asking I tried about 5hrs on my own, google and jquery documentation to solve it. May I ask where/how did you know about this $("#all > option:not([value ...    I had managed until $("#all > option[value :)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rkrara How i know about it? I just learn jquery.. and if you say in english what you need.. hide all options in #all that have not got filter in its value.. so `.hide()` `#all>option` `:not` `value*=filter`.. see list of selectors at https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/154_cheatsheet/jquery12_colorcharge.png

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
   $('#type').change(function(){
       var val_type = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
       $('option', '#all').each(function(){
           if( $(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(val_type) === -1 ){
               // Not right type
               $(this).prop('disabled', true).hide();
           } else {
               // Is right type
               $(this).prop('disabled', false).show();
           }
       });
       // If the selected option is not longer possible then choose the first possible option
       if( $('option', '#all').filter(':selected').is(':disabled') ){
           $('#all').val($('option', '#all').not(':disabled').first().val());
       }
   }).change(); 
});
```

Note: I have amde the comparision case-insenitive via toLowerCase() since otherwise nothing is selected.  See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ptF57/).

However, a better option performance-wise would be to add a class to each option in the #all select with which to match the allowed values.

Edit: just seen the filter button.  Had read it initially as wanting it on a change event so that is the way I have done it.  But not difficult to convert the code the run on the button click instead.

Edit: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k5RVZ/) is a version using classes which will be more efficient if the lists get big.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBunZ/)

of it working.

```
function Test(val){

    $("#all > option").each(function() {
        if(this.value.indexOf(val)== -1){
            $(this).remove();
        }
}); 
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. but this has a problem. When type list is changed/selected for second time everything is lost.

Comment: sorry heres a better one: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBunZ/1/) ` $(this).show();`